# Error in importing class in JavaScript object not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I am struggling to try to import a class in Javascript (located in the `leaflet-m2t.js` file) is there an error keeps getting thrown m2t is not defined. The file is getting imported just fine, and the error is not in the file but in my code. I would appreciate some help in addressing this problem

```
require('./leaflet-m2t.js')
$scope.tileProvider = new m2t.tileProvider({
    map: map,
    tileUrl: '/m2t',
    defaultLayer: 'Dark',
    tileLayers: [],
    outlineLayers: ['Light', {
        name: 'Dark',
        style: {
            "color": "#737373",
            "weight": 1,
            "fillOpacity": 1,
            "fillColor": "#0d0d0d",
            'backgroundColor': '#242425',
            'clickable': false
        }

                }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution to this problem happened to be is instead of importing the class via Javascript using the `require` statement, I had to import the JS Class file via an HTML tag `<script src="./leaflet-m2t.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

```
var m2t = require('./leaflet-m2t.js');
```

Unlike in Java you should define what you are importing, in this case the default export of leaflet. JavaScript doesn't magically know what you're referring to, this only works for global variables.

If leaflet uses es6 exports you will need to do:

```
var m2t = require('./leaflet-m2t.js').default;
```

Or if you have your app configured to handle es6 imports:

```
import m2t from './leaflet-m2t.js';
```

Comment: now i am getting an error `m2t.tileProvider is not a constructor`

Comment: Add how you are exporting your class in leaflet-m2t.js

Comment: what do you mean by exporting this

Comment: I've added more info, incase leaflet-m2t.js uses es6 exports instead of `module.exports`. If you open that file you can see how it is exporting.

Comment: ok so when I use `.default` i get an error that states `m2t is undefined` and then i used the import statement the error I get is `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: How is the class in `leaflet-m2t.js` exported?

Comment: there was no mention of the class in app.module.js but I added the following line in this file`require('./lib/leaflet-m2t.js').default;` and get the same error - I also tried the import statement and get the `m2t is not defined error` again

Comment: Sounds like an old library which adds to the `window` object, but can't know without seeing the file contents